# How to add transaction column field

Tags: netsuite

I tried to add transaction column fields and succeed.

Clicking Custmization/Lists,Records,Fields/Transaction Column Fields

Filling all contents necessary and checked options in Apply to Form.
But couldn't find it from sublist.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I made it completely same as other transaction column fields but it is working while my field is not working

Comment: Can you give screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason why it is not showing that field.

You need to make sure access is added correctly

Add in Subtab named 'Access/Role'

Administrator , Edit, Edit and etc.